# Width of a random convex polygon

Tags: pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry, random-walks

1. Consider a planar (2D) random walk comprised of N steps.
2. Consider the minimum convex polygon enclosing the N points visited by the random walker.
3. Assume the definition of the width of a convex polygon given in http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~orm/width.html

Is it possible to determine the probability density of the width of such a random convex polygon?

Comment: There is info available, not necessarily answering your precise question, e.g. [What's the average width of a convex polygon?](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/20936/237).

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke your link is about computing the average width (usually known as the "mean width") rather than what is wanted in this question, the (minimum) width.

Comment: You're looking for information on the convex hull of a random walk on which there is some literature. In particular, this paper of Spitzer and Widom http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1961-012-03/S0002-9939-1961-0130616-7/ computes the expected perimeter of such a polygon, using Cauchy's surface area formula which relates the perimeter to the mean width (averaged over projections onto lines in all directions). Unfortunately, I don't (yet?) see how to compute from their work anything about the minimum width (over all projections).

Comment: In 1941 Daniels was the first to investigate the extent or span of a 1D random walk. He actually determined the probability density of the span of a random walk in 1D. G.H. Weiss and R.J. Rubin generalized the notion of span to [multi-dimensional random walks](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01030198#). Spans are the sides of the smallest rectangular box with sides **parallel** to the coordinate axes that entirely contains the random walk. In 2D, they were able to determine the probability densities for the smallest and largest spans. This is as close as I could get to the answer.

Comment: A related and perhaps easier question might be the following: What is the distribution of the diameter of the smallest sphere entirely containing the random walk. This question was discussed by Weiss and Rubin [here](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/9780470142769.ch5/summary) in 1983. Is it possible that the question is still open? I tried combing the literature, but could not find anything. Perhaps I have missed some very important works.

Comment: Recent related paper: Kabluchko, Zakhar, Vladislav Vysotsky, and Dmitry Zaporozhets. "Convex hulls of random walks, hyperplane arrangements, and Weyl chambers." [arXiv:1510.04073](https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.04073) (2015).

Answer (score 7):

(Not an answer; rather an example.)

Here is a random walk with random $\pm 1$ $xy$-steps with equal probability (you didn't specify details), for $n=10^4$ steps, and its convex hull.

   [image: RandWalk10K]
And here is the very same random walk extended to $n=10^5$ steps:

   [image: RandWalk100K]

---

**Added** *15Oct15*. There is a new paper relevant to this question:

> Zakhar Kabluchko, Vladislav Vysotsky, and Dmitry Zaporozhets.
>   "Convex hulls of random walks, hyperplane arrangements, and Weyl chambers."
>   ([arXiv abstract](http://arxiv.org/abs/1510.04073).)
>
> "We give an explicit formula for the probability that the convex hull of an
>   $n$-step random walk in $\mathbb{R}^d$ with centrally symmetric density of increments
>   does not contain the origin."

By "contain" here they mean "strictly contain in the interior of the hull."

---

**Update** *1Apr2017*. The same authors have revised their paper,
establishing a formula for the expected number of $k$-dimensional faces of 
the convex hull of a random walk:

> Kabluchko, Zakhar, Vladislav Vysotsky, and Dmitry Zaporozhets. "Convex hulls of random walks: Expected number of faces and face probabilities." Revised 21 Aug 2017. ([arXiv:1612.00249 Abs](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.00249).)